# Checking to see if an image format supports a usage in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

If I want to see what an image format can be used for I can do the vkGetPhysicalDeviceImageFormatProperties2() and set the usage flag for the image format. I've noticed if the format isn't supported for those usages and settings the structure I pass in is set to all zero, and I can know if the format supports those uses. So if I want to know if VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_UINT supports sampling from a shader I set the VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT in the usage flags and call that function.

What I wanted to know is if that's equivalent to calling another function, called vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties2(), exactly the same name but without 'image' in the name, give that function the format, and check whether the VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT is set.

So using the first method I give the format and usages I want from it, and then check if the values returned are zero max width, max height, etc, meaning those usages aren't supported, versus the second method of passing the format, getting back the flags and then checking the flags.

Are these two methods equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Do your image format checking properly: ask how you can use the format, then ask what functionality is available from *usable* format&usage combinations.

If you call `vkGetPhysicalDeviceImageFormatProperties2` with usage flags and the like that don't correspond to a supported image type, you get an error: `VK_ERROR_FORMAT_NOT_SUPPORTED`. It inherits this due to the fact that it is said to "behave similarly to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceImageFormatProperties`", which has an explicit statement about this error:

> If `format` is not a supported image format, or if the combination of `format`, `type`, `tiling`, `usage`, and `flags` is not supported for images, then `vkGetPhysicalDeviceImageFormatProperties` returns `VK_ERROR_FORMAT_NOT_SUPPORTED`.

Now normally, a function which gives rise to an error will yield undefined values in any return values. But there [is a weird exception](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap41.html#VkImageFormatProperties2):

> If the combination of parameters to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceImageFormatProperties2` is not supported by the implementation for use in `vkCreateImage`, then all members of `imageFormatProperties` will be filled with zero.

However, there's an explicit note saying that this was old, bad behavior and is only preserved for compatibility's sake. Being a compatibility feature means that you can rely on it, but you *shouldn't*. Also, it only applies to the `imageFormatProperties` data and *not* any of the extension structures you can pass.

So it's best to just ignore this and ask your questions in the right order.